# Prove that: $M,N,R,Q$ are on the same circle.

Tags: geometry

Let cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $AD\cap BC=E,AB\cap CD=F,AC\cap EF=R,BD\cap EF=Q$.$M,N$
are mid-points of $BD,AC$. Prove that: $M,N,R,Q$ are on the same circle.
[image]

Here is what I tried:

Put: $K=MN \cap EF$ so by Gauss's line theorem, have $K$ is mid-point of $EF$.

Easy to see that: $(FE,RQ)=-1$ $\Rightarrow KE^2=KF^2 = KR.KQ$ (Newton)

So just need to prove that: $KE^2=KM.KN$ which is my problem.

Can anyone help me from this? Thank you a lots!f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

Notice that $EAC \stackrel-\sim EBD$. Since $N$ is the midpoint of $AC$ and $M$ is the midpoint of $BD$, it follows that $EAN \stackrel-\sim EBM$. Hence, using directed angles, $\angle ANE = \angle EMB$ and completely analogously $\angle FNA = \angle DMF$. Addition of these two identities gives $$\angle FNE = \angle FNA + \angle ANE = \angle DMF + \angle EMB = \angle DMB - \angle FME = - \angle FME.$$ Therefore, let $M'$ be the reflection of $M$ in $K$ such that $\angle FNE = \angle FM'E$ and hence $FNEM'$ is cyclic. Now $$KM \cdot KN = - KM' \cdot KN = - KF \cdot KE = KE^2,$$ and we finish by your first observations.